# How to show an error if user has not opted city from google map auto complete

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am finding a way to show user an error if user has not selected city from Google Autocomplete list. Is there a way to find it?

Currently I am using below code for `autocomplete`

```
var txt_frm_addmarker_city  = document.getElementById('frm_addmarker_city');

var city_autocomplete_options = {
    language: 'it-IT',
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "it"}
};

var autocomplete_txt_frm_addmarker_city = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(txt_frm_addmarker_city, city_autocomplete_options);

// Add Marker form:: Get Position of Place (City)
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete_txt_frm_addmarker_city, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete_txt_frm_addmarker_city.getPlace();
    if ('undefined' != typeof place.geometry) {

        var lat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
            lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

        var randomGeoPoints = generateRandomPoints({'lat':lat, 'lng':lng}, 5000, 1);

        jQuery("input[name='latitude']").val(randomGeoPoints[0].lat);
        jQuery("input[name='longitude']").val(randomGeoPoints[0].lng);          
    }
    else {
        alertMagnificPopup("Error");
    }
});
```

So basically I want user to select city from Google Autocomplete only. I don't want user to just type **XYZ** in city field. So is there any way to show user an error and do not allow to proceed further?

Comment: In the else section where you have alertMagnificPopup("Error"); do some function that clears the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flag variable here to verify that like:

```
var isOptionSelected = false;

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete_txt_frm_addmarker_city, 'place_changed', function() {
    isOptionSelected = true;
    // your map option select logic here
});

// On submit button click you can verify that
document.getElementById("submitForm").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (!isOptionSelected){
        alert('Please select an option from autocomplete');
        return;  // skip an further form processing logic
    }

    // Reset the flag state here
    isOptionSelected = false;

    // Now, continue with your logic
});
```